# Continue FOR-NEXT loop even if IF-THEN condition not met

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

My current FOR-NEXT loop works as long as the IF-THEN condition is met.  However, as soon as the IF-THEN condition is not met, the loop stops.  I want the loop to continue, even if the IF-THEN condition is not met.  I want to check ALL lines in the table.  New to VBA.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Dim EngHisTable As ListObject

Set EngHisTable = Sheets("Historic").ListObjects("Table2")

Dim WeekCode As String
WeekCode = Sheets("Weekly").Range("B5").Value

For x = EngHisTable.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1

    If EngHisTable.ListRows(EngHisTable.ListRows.Count).Range(, 15) = WeekCode Then
        EngHisTable.ListRows(EngHisTable.ListRows.Count).Delete
    End If

Next x
```

Comment: You're not actually using `x` within your loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually using `x` within your loop. If you were to do so, it would look like this:

```
For x = EngHisTable.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If EngHisTable.ListRows(x).Range(, 15) = WeekCode Then
        EngHisTable.ListRows(x).Delete
    End If
Next x
```

Alternately, you can filter and then delete all rows corresponding to `WeekCode` in one go, instead of looping row by row:

```
Sub MyDelete()
    Dim EngHisTable As ListObject
    Set EngHisTable = Sheets("Historic").ListObjects("Table2")

    Dim WeekCode As String
    WeekCode = Sheets("Weekly").Range("B5").Value

    With EngHisTable
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=WeekCode

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim rngToDelete As Range
        Set rngToDelete = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
    End With
End Sub
```